# I need good gedolim stories

Tags: sources-mekorot

I am looking for really good stories about gedolim that may not be so well known to everyone but that have sources. Any ideas who or where to look?

Comment: See if you can get hold of the really old typewriter Agudah pamphlets for *madrichim*.

Comment: Maybe obscure midrashim

Comment: Making of a gadol